# What is the fastest way to generate the first n powers of 2?

Tags: python-3.x, math, optimization, exponent

I'm writing in Python, and any tiny optimizations would help (I'm 0.01 seconds off the time limit). I need to generate a list of the first n powers of 2:

```
[1, 2, 4, ... 2 ^ n]
```

I have a few pieces of code written now:

```
powers = [1 << i for i in range(n)]
```

or

```
powers = [1 for i in range(n)]
for i in range(1, n):
    powers[i] = powers[i - 1] * 2
```

What optimizations can i make to these pieces of code, or is there a new way of approaching the problem entirely?

Comment: <strikethrough>The bitshifting approach runs in O(n), while the incrementing approach runs in O(n^2), so the former should be faster.</strikethrough> You should probably benchmark it to be sure though: https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html. The only way I could think of that might speed it up is by using vector operations in numpy, but I'm not sure how much that would help.

Comment: How does the second one approach O(n^2)? It runs through a loop of length n twice. The reason I thought it might be more effective than the first is because it uses a DP-like approach, in that it builds on the previous solutions, which I thought might be a bit faster than generating a new number every time with the first way. However, I didn't know of this library - that helps a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, whoops, I misread the code. Sorry, you're right. They both run in O(n), disregard that part. In any case, you're best off profiling it.

Comment: try using `xrange` instead of `range`. For large N it will make a difference.

Comment: @miraculixx , sorry I should've clarified, I'm using Python 3.5

Comment: If you're 0.01 seconds off the time limit, have you tried just resubmitting the same code repeatedly and seeing if you can get a slightly faster time by pure luck?

Comment: No, sadly their judge is quite consistent. It's just one test case in 50 that I'm getting too long on.

Comment: Have you tried creating a large list *without* the calculations (i.e., `biggie = [1,2,4,8,...]`) and then getting a slice (`actual = biggie[:n+1]`)? Don't know if that would be faster but you should be benchmarking every suggestion anyway. I'd also consider using `[1] * n` in the pre-make-the-list option, that's likely to create the list in one hit whereas the `1 for i in range` option *may* be continuously extending the list.

Comment: Since n can go as high as 1000, I'm not sure that would be a plausible solution to include in the code. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @Andi, you can write a meta-program to generate the list initialisation.

Comment: Another option is, of course, to create the list in native C rather than Python.

Comment: At 100 repeated checks of 1000 sequential `[math.pow(2,i) for i in range(1000)]` runs in 0.146 in average; `[2**i for i in range(1000)]` -- in 0.308; building list from generator, which shifts last result left by one -- in 0.072; `[1<<i for i in range(1000)]` -- in 0.046 at my machine

Comment: But for large numbers, generator approach runs at O(N). So the answer depends on how large list do you need. Also there may be some optimizations for `1<<i` list comprehension, maybe there aren't -- need to dig deeper into cpython sources. At least you could experimentally determine, when `1<<i` performance drops and switch to generator. O(N) and O(N^2) are just asymptotics at infinity, for finites they usually vary

Comment: Is there *nothing* else in your program that you can optimize? This seems like the last place I'd look.

Comment: @miraculixx that only works in python2, in python3 range() is the same as xrange()

Comment: @Blender, yes, I've optimized as much as possible. Instead of using input(), I'm reading all input at once with sys.stdin.read() and parsing manually. I created my own hash function for 2 integers instead of using a nested dictionary. Instead of using an array of booleans, I changed representation to a binary number and found functions to a bit at the n'th digit. I'm using DP as well, and minimzed uses of "dots" (e.g. instead of doing lst.append() in a loop, set append=lst.append and use append() in the loop. The list goes on, I've tried literally everything. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @AndiGu: I don't think you're going to extract any more speed out of that statement. Post the rest of your code, I'm sure something else can be tweaked.

Comment: Because it's a constant list, can you try just generating the list once at the start and use it for all subsequent tests? Or just generate a list of all constants if possible. It won't be too large unless n is extremely large

Comment: @AndiGu: Some of those measures sound counterproductive. Manually parsing `sys.stdin.read()` sounds easy to get wrong, and a custom hash function would probably perform a lot worse than just relying on the built-in tuple hash. I'd guess you're still missing some important algorithmic improvement.

Comment: Does it have to be a list or an iterable? `map(lambda x: 1 << x, range(n)` Is probably as fast as I can think of.

Comment: @StevenSummers" `[1 << i for i in range(n)]` will be faster than use of `map` with `lambda` function. You may try it by your own

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I did test it. I get `0.000588` using `map` and `0.0962` using list comp. Only if it has to be a list then you need to cast the map object to a list `list(map(...))` which is slower than list comp. If it just need to be iterable then `map` is much faster. I had `n` as 1000

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for all your help and feedback; however, I managed to sort of hack a solution (I didn't change my code, I just submitted using the PyPy3 language, and I guess there was a small improvement in time and my code was approved). Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Have you tried this: instead of doing `[1 << i]` for every `i`, you do it inductively: create an array `a`, such that `a[0] = 1` and `a[i] = a[i - 1] << 1`. Since your `n` can go as high as `1000`, this might be faster than your approach. It still somehow depends on the interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

A good interpreter will convert multiplication by 2 and left shift into the same bytecode instruction(s).So both the approaches should eventually translate to same bytecode,hence same speed.